# C++ Class Constructor With Array Member Variable

Tags: c++, arrays, class, c++11

I'm working on a problem where I'm to build a class with 40 integer array to calculate addition and subtraction on 40 digit numbers.

I've written below code, but for some reason, it's keep failing with an error message:

```
Implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::_1::array<int, 40>'.
```

I don't understand the error message and do not see any issue with the code. Could you please help?

Also, as you can see, I'm using memcpy function, but when I just enter `std::memcpy( hugeInteger, integer, sizeof( integer ) )`, it spits out `No viable conversion from 'std::array<int, 40>' to 'void'.`
As I understand, `memcpy` accepts pointer, and `hugeInteger` is a pointer to the first element of an array. Am I not understanding correctly?

Below is the header:

```
#ifndef __Chapter_9__HugeInteger__
#define __Chapter_9__HugeInteger__

#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

class HugeInteger
{
public:
    explicit HugeInteger( bool = 1, std::array< int, 40 > = {} );
    void setHugeInteger( std::array< int, 40 > );
    void print();

private:
    bool checkHugeInteger( std::array< int, 40 > );

    std::array< int, 40 > hugeInteger = {};
    bool sign;
};

#endif /* defined(__Chapter_9__HugeInteger__) */
```

Below is the cpp:

```
#include <array>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "HugeInteger.h"

HugeInteger::HugeInteger( bool sign, std::array< int, 40 > integer )
: sign(sign)
{
    setHugeInteger( integer );
}

void HugeInteger::setHugeInteger( std::array< int, 40 > integer )
{
    if ( checkHugeInteger( integer ) )
        std::memcpy( hugeInteger, integer, sizeof( integer ) );
    else
        throw std::invalid_argument( "Single digit in the huge integer may not be negative ");
}

bool HugeInteger::checkHugeInteger( std::array< int, 40 > integer )
{
    bool tester = 1;

    for ( int i = int( integer.size() ) - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
    {
        if ( integer[i] < 0 )
        {
            tester = 0;
            break;
        }
    }

    return tester;
}

void HugeInteger::print()
{
    if ( sign < 0 )
        std::cout << "-";

    for( int i = int( hugeInteger.size() ) - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
        std::cout << hugeInteger[ i ];
}
```

Comment: The header should have `#include <array>`

Comment: I'd pass the array by const reference to avoid copying.

Comment: @McNabb: #include <array> did not solve the problem ;(

Comment: @zenith: I'm trying to initialize 'hugeInteger.' That is why I'm assigning '= {}' to the array. If I do 'explicit HugeInteger( bool = 1, std::array< int, 40 >& = {} );,' wouldn't this assign the reference itself to {}?

Comment: @McNabb: NVM! It actually did! Yay~! ... Now I feel so dumb... This took me 2 hours...

Comment: `__Chapter_9__HugeInteger__` is a reserved identifier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't get the error you mention, using your exact code. However your code does not have a `main` function. So I presume there is another `.cpp` file that you haven't mentioned which contains `main`. If so, the error could be because that file includes `HugeInteger.h` without doing `#include <array>`.

The `HugeInteger.h` should do `#include <array>` itself, instead of relying on other includers to do it.

To fix the `memcpy` problem, replace the `memcpy` line with:

```
hugeInteger = integer;
```

The `std::array` container has value semantics, so you can assign it.

I'd also recommend changing your functions which accept an `array` to take it by const reference. This will avoid unnecessary copies when functions are called.  Also, the `checkHugeInteger` function could be `static` as it does not use any member variables of the class.

Comment: Thank you for your response and the tips. By the way, if I were to use memcpy, what am I doing wrong? Is there any problem with my memcpy statement?

Comment: Oh by the way, the main function only has two lines:
    HugeInteger integer;
    integer.print();

Comment: @GrinNare Yes the `memcpy` statement is wrong. `memcpy` needs two pointers as parameters, you're passing `std::array`.

Comment: @zenith: (Correct me if I'm wrong here) As I understand if...
    int b[5];
    int *bPtr;
Then...
    bPtr == &b[0] == b, which means the array name 'b' itself is a point, no?

Comment: @GrinNare C-style arrays decay to a pointer to the first element, however `std::array` does not (which is one of the main reasons for `std::array` existing in the first place)